# PHPUnit Selenium HTML report

Tags: php, selenium, automation, phpunit

I am using phpunit with selenium for automation. Anybody have any idea about plugin for HTML report for this. Like i want to display reports of passed and failed testes in any web browser with nice view, rather than phpunit console output.

Comment: I don't know about HTML report but you can made a screenshot for nice view! You can see details about screenshort at http://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/selenium.html

Comment: There are some plugins for Jenkins. For instance, http://s3.hostingkartinok.com/uploads/images/2014/01/d0d2c96b5a954397c6d35ef311a89e4a.png